# Kendo Grid Date Filter wont work with my JSON data

Tags: json, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid from Telerik and running into a problem. I want to filter the data server side using a date filter. So i found a running example, which works as I expect:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        OrderDate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
          {
              field: "OrderDate",
              title: "Order Date",
              format: "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}",
              parseFormats: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
              headerTemplate: '<label for="check-all"><b>Start Date</b></label>',
              headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;" },
              attributes: { style: "text-align:center !important;padding-right: 25px;" },
              filterable: {
                  ui: function (element) {
                      element.kendoDatePicker({
                          format: "MMM dd, yyyy"
                      });
                  }
              }
          }
        ]
    });
});
```

Now i changed this example for my needs. I'm using a REST API call that returns JSON data. The data is shown in the grid, but when i try to aplly a filter the data is lost. It seems, that something is wrong with the date format, but i don't know what is the correct way to go. Here is my code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://localhost/FPT2015.WebApp/api/BereitschaftszeitStammdaten",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "d.results",
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        stundeVon: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
                , parse: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, val) {
                        val.stundeVon = new Date(val.stundeVon);
                    });
                    return data;
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        height: 550,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
          {
              field: "stundeVon",
              title: "Order Date",
              format: "{0:MMM dd, yyyy}",
              parseFormats: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
              headerTemplate: '<label for="check-all"><b>Start Date</b></label>',
              headerAttributes: { style: "text-align: center;" },
              attributes: { style: "text-align:center !important;padding-right: 25px;" },
              filterable: {
                  ui: function (element) {
                      element.kendoDatePicker({
                          format: "MMM dd, yyyy"
                      });
                  }
              }
          }
        ]
    });
});
```

And this is the JSON, that my API returns:

```
{
    "d":{
        "__count":6,
        "results":[
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":2,
                "bereitschaftlerId":1,
                "stundeVon":"2015-11-25T06:00:00+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2015-12-07T07:00:00+01:00"
            },
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":5,
                "bereitschaftlerId":2,
                "stundeVon":"2015-12-07T06:00:00+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2015-12-14T06:00:00+01:00"
            },
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":7,
                "bereitschaftlerId":1,
                "stundeVon":"2016-01-10T10:00:00+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2016-01-17T10:00:00+01:00"
            },
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":12,
                "bereitschaftlerId":13,
                "stundeVon":"2016-01-03T10:00:00+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2016-01-10T10:00:00+01:00"
            },
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":15,
                "bereitschaftlerId":2,
                "stundeVon":"2016-01-18T06:00:00+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2016-02-19T06:00:00+01:00"
            },
            {
                "bereitschaftszeitId":44,
                "bereitschaftlerId":2,
                "stundeVon":"2016-03-11T12:06:21.207+01:00",
                "stundeBis":"2017-03-11T00:06:00+01:00"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Does anybody see, what I'm doing wrong here? I would be glad, if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poblem here was my server side code (C#). The filter logic got correctly passed to the server, but there I had a Linq DynamicQuery which was not able to handle a Where-String like:

`Where(@"StundeVon == ""Tue Mar 08 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)""")`

I updated the expression, to use paramters and it works now. It looks something like this:

`Where(@"StundeVon == @0", new DateTime(2016,3,8))`

Thank you for your help David. It got me on the right track. The time-part was a thing, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have produced a simple dojo for you to see hopefully the expected result: 
http://dojo.telerik.com/eXEFO

All I have done is tweaked the date parsing element to this:

```
 val.stundeVon = new Date(val.stundeVon);
 val.stundeVon.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

When you are comparing the dates it will be doing an `exact` match which means that if you are not providing the time element as part of your filtering then the system will match a date based on it being **dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss** and in the filtering it will be applying the date element but always providing 00:00:00 as the time portion.

So all I have done is force the time portion to be set to the default 00:00:00 and then the filtering works as expected.

If this is not the expected behaviour and the time element is important then change the filter control to a date time picker and this should then pass the time portion as well.

**Note: I have changed the filtering, paging etc to client side for this example to work**

any issues give me a shout.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i will check that!